# Удалить из атрибута определенный символ jquery

Tags: jquery, атрибуты

Есть такой атрибут `my-attr="1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19"` возможно ли из этого атрибута удалить *11,* на чистом *jQuery*?

На JavaScript выглядит так:

```
// Удаление элемента из массива.
Array.prototype.remove = function(value)
{
    var idx = this.indexOf(value);
    if (idx != -1)
    {
        // Второй параметр - число элементов, которые необходимо удалить
        return this.splice(idx, 1);
    }
    return false;
}


var str = $('.class').attr('my-attr');
var n_arr = str.split(',');

n_arr.remove('11');

console.log(n_arr);
```

Возможно ли на *jQuery* сделать похожее, но по короче?

Comment: А вариант на JavaScript не подойдет? Почему?

Comment: Слишком длинный код. :-(

Comment: вариантов нет никаких?

Comment: Я только на JavaScript умею. Увы.

Comment: @N0ob jquery этот прежде всего фреймворк для манипуляций с dom.  Если хотите манипулировать массивами - возьмите underscore -http://underscorejs.org/#without

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
n_arr = jQuery.grep(n_arr, function( a ) {
  return a !== '11';
});
```

Но я бы на вашем месте взял http://underscorejs.org/#without. jQuery не создан для активной работы с чистыми данными.

```
n_arr = _.without(n_arr, '11');
```

Comment: Самое оно. Спасибо за without